# how to solve Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, kohana

The flv videos are usually uploaded to our Google Drive and also create to the iframe

like

```
<iframe height="272" style="margin-top:-270px; position:absolute" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwgCehvr2FnlU3cwTTVzUXN5SXM/preview" width="440"></iframe>
```

some browser in It shows up as "Whoops! There was a problem playing this video. Download" But if we click the 'pop out' button on the upper right, the video opens on a seperate tab and it plays.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://docs.google.com/get_video_info?docid=0BwFh_4qf05UOYnkxLW9Mb3dJRFU&authuser=0.
>   Redirect from
>   'https://docs.google.com/get_video_info?docid=0BwFh_4qf05UOYnkxLW9Mb3dJRFU&authuser=0'
>   to
>   'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=writely&passive=1209600&co…tps://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwFh_4qf05UOYnkxL&ltmpl=homepage&authuser=0'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'https://drive.google.com' is therefore not allowed access.

how to solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, must give access from the server. Years ago uses crossdomain.xml from flash ( macromedia)

Comment: the issue is with chrome only. In some chorme browsers it works and some were not.

Comment: You can't make an ajax request unless you have correct headers set on the server side to allow access.

Comment: The answer is in the error message: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"...

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a problem with Google Drive at the moment:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/uACJyxwGbU0